# FollowHyperlink event not working

Tags: vba, excel

FollowHyperlink event not FIRE when I use it with hyperlink function :

```
=IF(C8505=0;IF(F8505=0;"";IF(H8505=0;"Nothing";IF(G8505="Memo";HYPERLINK("\\scan2014\memo\"&H8505&".pdf";" Link ");HYPERLINK("\\scan2014\"&H8505&".pdf";"Link"))));IF(H8505=0;VLOOKUP("*"&Inbox!$C8505&"*";Sheet1!A:C;1;FALSE);IF(G8505="Memo";HYPERLINK("\\scan2014\memo\"&H8505&".pdf";VLOOKUP("*"&Inbox!$C8505&"*";Sheet1!A:C;1;FALSE));HYPERLINK("\\scan2014\"&H8505&".pdf";VLOOKUP("*"&Inbox!$C8505&"*";Sheet1!A:C;1;FALSE)))))
```

My code that I want to fire is :

```
Private Sub Worksheet_FollowHyperlink(ByVal Target As Hyperlink)
LastR = Sheets("Track").Range("a10000").End(xlUp).Row + 1

With Worksheets("Track")
.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Sheets("Track").Range("a" & LastR), _
Address:="", _
SubAddress:="inbox!" & Target.Parent.Address, _
ScreenTip:=Target.Parent.Address
End With

 End Sub
```

Comment: see this link: [Worksheet_FollowHyperlink and MsgBox not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9828260/worksheet-followhyperlink-and-msgbox-not-working-in-excel-2010)

Answer (score 3):

This is by design.  The **HYPERLINK()** function does not raise the event, **Inserted** hyperlinks do raise the event.  If you need the event to be raised, modify your formula to jump to a **transfer** cell in the worksheet, like Z100.

In Z100 place an **Inserted**  hyperlink to get to the final destination.

This way to get the flexibility of a formula and the macro capability at the same time.