# hyperlinks(1).address only returning a partial address

Tags: excel, sharepoint, hyperlink, vba

I'm working on the following code, which will re-format a cell containing a link based on whether or not the link works when it is clicked:

```
Private Sub worksheet_followhyperlink(ByVal HL As HYPERLINK)
Dim linkReq As Object
Dim linkStatus As Integer

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
On Error GoTo linkError
Set linkReq = New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
With linkReq
    .Open "GET", HL.address, False
    .Send
End With
linkStatus = linkReq.Status

If linkStatus = 404 Then HL.Parent.Interior.Color = rgbPink
If linkStatus <> 404 Then HL.Parent.Interior.Pattern = xlNone

If HL.Parent.Interior.Pattern = xlNone Then GoTo exitSub
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
MsgBox("Link is broken")

exitSub:
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Exit Sub

linkError:
linkStatus = 404
Resume Next
End Sub
```

The code worked great yesterday!  But now, it's returning everything as '404' and marking the cells pink, even if the links work.  Debugging reveals that the value of HL.address is "folder/Document.pdf" instead of "https://website/folder/Document.pdf".  This excel document is hosted on "https://website" through sharepoint.

The code not working because of the truncation.

Is there a way to extract a full url from an excel hyperlink, without truncation, regardless of the size of the url?

Comment: Re-adding the hyperlink fixes the problem.  My workaround for the moment is going to be creating a workbook_open macro that reloads all of the hyperlinks ...

Comment: This workaround has stopped working.  In certain cases, the hyperlink grew long enough that even a freshly populated hyperlink returns an address in the form "../../folder/Document.pdf"

Comment: My current workaround is using a UDF to store the full hyperlink as a string within the cell, and using that to reapply the hyperlink on workbook open as well as as a reference during error checking.  This came with separate issues of optimization, which have been solved.  The =HYPERLINK function cannot be used, because clicking on such a hyperlink does not trigger the followHyperlink event.

Comment: What do you have for the value of CurDir() ?

Comment: Debug.Print CurDir() = C:\Users\matt2103\Desktop

Comment: Ok, that rules out my initial explanation. Now, I'm curious to know what you meant by "such a hyperlink" in your previous comment. What do you get when you hover over the cell with the mouse? `https://website/folder/Document.pdf` or `folder/Document.pdf`?

Comment: @DecimalTurn A =HYPERLINK() hyperlink is not treated as a hyperlink by Excel.  It does not show up if you attempt to list hyperlinks on the sheet, nor does following it trigger the worksheet_followHyperlink event (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22113911/followhyperlink-event-not-working).  Hovering, however, does show the full address.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that Excel is changing your hyperlinks adresses from absolute to relative.

You can try to force absolute adress by changing so called "Hyperlink Base". In order to do it go to: File > Info > Show All Properties > Hyperlink Base (on the right of screen) and change it to "x".

Reference from Microsoft Support site:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/903163/how-to-create-absolute-hyperlinks-and-relative-hyperlinks-in-word-docu

(Article presents solution for MS Word but it should work in MS Excel as well)

Hope that helps.

Comment: This appears to work!  Moreover, it has shown me more of the inner workings of MS Office! Thank you, and welcome to stackoverflow :)  I'm going to give the question another 24 hours, just in case there's a more elegant answer out there (unlikely, but you never know), and then you will get the bounty.  Thanks again!

Comment: I'm glad it works for you! I have been long-time stackoverflow lurker and decided that it's about time to create an account  and try to solve some interesting issues :)

Comment: Further to Tom's answer, you can read/write to the Hyperlink Base programmatically using `ActiveWorkbook.BuiltinDocumentProperties("Hyperlink Base")` - (other ways to reference your workbook are available `;-)`  )

Comment: This did not work for me in excel. I did some further digging and found the Subaddress property which helped.

Answer (score 2):

The range object in excel has a second property "Subaddress" . 
Use the Subaddress  functionality to get the rest of the address like below

```
range.Hyperlinks(1).Address + range.Hyperlinks(1).SubAddress
```

In my case I had to add additional characters in between Address and Subaddress. Please make sure to check how the full URL can be formed using both Address and Subaddress

Comment: This answer was very helpful in figuring out another issue for me. I do want to note, it appears that Excel uses the "#" character as the delimiter in the SubAddress and it doesn't include that character in either .Address or .SubAddress, so if you want the full address it should be `range.Hyperlinks(1).Address & "#" & range.Hyperlinks(1).SubAddress` ... this is assuming there is no other delimiter it uses. I don't know because the MS documentation doesn't talk about it.