# Run macro when clicking on hyperlink that directs to another worksheet

Tags: excel, vba, events, hyperlink, vlookup

I have two worksheets. Sheet1 has a list of work orders (Column A) and Sheet2 has a list of material numbers that were purchased against the work orders. There will only be one work order entry in Sheet1 but there can be multiple material numbers linked to one work order.

Sheet2 will look something like this;

ColumnA    ColumnB

Order1     Material1

Order1     Material2

Order2     Material1

Order3     Material1

I have a hyperlink-vlookup combo that once a work order number is clicked in Sheet1 it will go to the same work order number in Sheet2 where the material is listed.

Now I want to run a macro after the hyperlink is clicked so that Sheet2 is filtered to only show material that were purchased against that work order. I tried the following which did not work. Please help!

```
Private Sub Worksheet_FollowHyperlink(ByVal Target As Hyperlink) 
     MsgBox "Run Code"   
End Sub
```

Comment: There is an event called Worksheet_SelectionChange, however I am not familiar enough with it to provide a complete answer, but I think this is what you need

Comment: Can you provide a snapshot of how your hyperlinked cells are setup in your sheet?

Comment: =HYPERLINK("#"&ADDRESS(MATCH(M2,Sheet2!A:A),2,,,"Goods Movement"),IFERROR(VLOOKUP(M2,Sheet2!A:M,2,FALSE),""))

Comment: [The issue that you have is that the `HYPERLINK` formula doesn't trigger the `FollowHyperlink` event. You will either need to do this via a `SelectionChange` event or have a look at this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22115070/3042759)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [FollowHyperlink event not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22113911/followhyperlink-event-not-working)

Answer (score 0):

The issue that you have is that the `FollowHyperlink` isn't triggered on a calculated hyperlink (i.e. not a static hyperlink but generated via the `HYPERLINK` function). You could get around this by using the `SelectionChange` event and testing for a hyperlink. This will need to be inserted into the sheet object

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim linkAddress As String
    On Error Resume Next
    linkAddress = Target.Hyperlinks(1).SubAddress
    On Error GoTo 0
    If linkAddress = vbNullString Then
        MsgBox "Run Code"
    End If
End Sub
```

or use the solution that I have marked as duplicate in the comments

Comment: The problem is that the macro is triggered every time you select something new on the sheet. 'SheetFollowHyperlink' works if you select a hyperlink that is linked to a cell on the same sheet. But if there is no way to make it work when the hyperlink directs you to another sheet then I will have to find another way.

Comment: Yes, that's what this event is designed to do and I understand that, but this tests for the hyperlink and if there isn't one it exits.It's not really a big deal and is a lot easier then statically programming all your hyperlinks or finding a workaround. Or you can use the solution in the post I linked to where you use an intermediary additional column

Comment: If you are worried about it getting triggered to often, you can use `Workbook_SheetActivate`. As your hyper link takes you to a different sheet, this would only get triggered when a sheet is activated. You can use @Tom code in there to ensure that it only gets triggered for hyperlink cells