# Excel - Pull data from a cell on a different sheet, hyperlink & highlight row

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I have a formula to pull data from a cell on a different sheet and link it to that cell. `=HYPERLINK("#"&ADDRESS(ROW(Sheet2!A2), COLUMN(Sheet2!A2), 4, 1, "Sheet2"), Sheet2!A2)` I was wondering if its possible to link it to the cell and highlight the row at the same time? Anything helps, thanks.

Comment: Highlight the link destination row?  When would the highlighting occur?  When the user clicks the link?

Comment: @TimWilliams Yes, the user would click the link and it would bring them to that cell on the separate sheet and highlight the row the cell is in.

Comment: There's a `Workbook_SheetFollowHyperlink` event which you could use to highlight the target row.

Comment: @TimWilliams I need it as a formula though, not using VBA

Comment: You can't do it with a formula.

Comment: @TimWilliams I can get that event to work with an inserted hyperlink, but not with the `HYPERLINK` function.

Comment: @BigBen Same issue here

Comment: You're right I had forgotten/did not know that - possible workaround here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46238345/run-macro-when-clicking-on-hyperlink-that-directs-to-another-worksheet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a workaround which will allow you to keep using `HYPERLINK()`

Put this in a regular module:

```
Public Function Go(Addr)
    Dim arr, rng
    arr = Split(Addr, "!")
    Set rng = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Replace(arr(0), "'", "")).Range(arr(1))
    rng.EntireRow.Interior.Color = vbYellow  '<< set row color
    Set Go = rng                             '<< return where to link to
End Function
```

Then modify your hyperlink to this:

```
=HYPERLINK("#Go("""&ADDRESS(ROW(Sheet2!A2), COLUMN(Sheet2!A2), 4, 1, "Sheet2") & """)", Sheet2!A2)
```

This works because a hyperlink address can be a function call - as long as the function knows what range to return as the link destination you're good to go.  The function can perform other actions before returning though, such as highlight a row in this case.  Might need to add some code to clear previous highlights.

---

To add, since I think this is useful: you can use this approach instead of adding command buttons to rows in tables of data - if you need an "action' such as edit/save you can create two functions:

```
Public Function EditRow(rowNum)
    Debug.Print "Set up editing for row " & rowNum
    Set EditRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(rowNum, 1) '<< link back to same cell
End Function

Public Function SaveRow(rowNum)
    Debug.Print "Saving row " & rowNum
    Set SaveRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(rowNum, 2) '<< link back to same cell
End Function
```

Then a couple of hyperlinks on each row:

```
=HYPERLINK("#EditRow(" & ROW() & ")","Edit")
=HYPERLINK("#SaveRow(" & ROW() & ")","Edit")
```

The only downside is you can't debug your functions when calling them this way.