# Scroll from hyperlink event

Tags: vba

simple question that I am stuck with. I am trying to set a function that scrolls the active cell to the top of the screen and then selects that entire row (to make it 100% obvious what data to look at)

However this is doing nothing, how do I fix that?

```
Sub FollowHyperlink(ByVal Target As Hyperlink)

    ActiveWindow.SmallScroll up:=2

    ActiveCell.EntireRow.Select

End Sub
```

Additionally.

Is there any other specifics that (ByVal Target As Hyperlink) needs to work. My hyperlink is formula based, which is a link to the location of pivot table raw data from a summary pivot table.

=HYPERLINK("#"&CELL("address", INDEX(DATA!H:R,MATCH(I2,DATA!H:H,0),11)), CONCAT("O",MATCH(I2,DATA!H:H,0)))

which basically just returns the row number for a unique variable.

Comment: It seems that I misunderstood your question the first time. I think your question is a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22113911/followhyperlink-event-not-working). I think the answer there will help.

Comment: thanks, I had a read through but don't quite understand what the linked code is achieving