# Excel - VBA code linked to Hyperlink not running

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to get some VBA code running when I click a hyperlink in excel.  I am using the following test code but it is not working.  I have tried placing the code (VBA editor) in the sheet, thisworkbook, and it's own module.  Nothing works.  What am I doing wrong?  Is there some master setting that must be configure to run VBA code? I'm sure it's simple. :)

```
Sub Worksheet_FollowHyperlink(ByVal Target As Hyperlink)
    MsgBox "It Ran"
End Sub
```

Comment: I put it in the Worksheet and it worked just fine for me. Maybe what you are clicking on isn't a hyperlink?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22113911/followhyperlink-event-not-working

Comment: What do you want to happen when the link is clicked?

Comment: OK, I made some progress.  I made a basic hyperlink to another cell and it worked.  My original hyperlink was a button shape with the same hyperlink to the same cell.  The VBA code does not run in that instance. Why would that be?  I set up the hyperlink the same way in both senarios.  Once just has a button shape on it.

Comment: After more googling it seems VBA code will not execute when the hyperlink is inside a shape.  Please let me know if this is untrue or maybe a work around. thx