# Excel Hyperlink to run userform based on row

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2007

I have a workbook that all data is managed through userforms, no manual input. I wanted to make it easier to edit a row by making one of the colums called "Edit" with this as its formula :

`=HYPERLINK("Edit:>8";"Click to Edit"`)

The "8" is the row id number automatically added when creating the row

I thought this would work, but aparrently the hyperlink address needs to be valid for this event to trigger :

```
Private Sub Worksheet_FollowHyperlink(ByVal Target As Hyperlink)

    If Left(Target.Address, 8) = "Edit:>" Then
        editRow(Right(Target.Adress,9))
    End If    

End Sub
```

Any workarounds or better ideas?

Comment: does spelling `Address` correctly help when passing the argument to `editRow` (or is it just a typo)?

Comment: @ScottHoltzman typo, the code is never actually triggered

Comment: How about `Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick`? This way the cell could look like you want it... also a "normal click" would not trigger any events... (I use it very often, because I never have any use for the normal double click behavior)...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to insert the hyperlink via `Ctrl-K` shortcut and it works:

[image: Adding new hyperlink]

and this code

```
Private Sub Worksheet_FollowHyperlink(ByVal Target As Hyperlink)

    Dim rowNum As Long
    rowNum = CLng(Replace(Replace(Target.Address, "https://row", ""), ".com/", ""))

    MsgBox "You are about to edit row " & rowNum

End Sub
```

returns

[image: Message box result]

**But it gets better** -- you don't even need to parse the row number from the URL as `Hyperlink` object provides `Range` method that you can use to determine the row where it was clicked:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_FollowHyperlink(ByVal Target As Hyperlink)

    MsgBox "You are about to edit " & Target.Range.Address

End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: that's a beautiful answer, but I must be doing something wrong because it is trying to acess the address trough the browser, excel 2007

Comment: Hmm, it doesn't happen for me. Once I added `Worksheet_FollowHyperlink` method it completes the sub and doesn't open the browser. I use Excel 2010. There must be a way to cancel the event.

Comment: Ah it works now, just had remove and add the method again, thanks!

Comment: create the hyperlink with something like: `ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Range("A1"), Address:="", SubAddress:="Sheet1!A1", TextToDisplay:="My text here."` this way the cell will just lead to itself...

Answer (score 0):

The HyperLink function doesn't work that way - it's intended not to trigger the FollowHyperlink event.

See:

[Worksheet_FollowHyperlink and MsgBox not working in Excel 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9828260/worksheet-followhyperlink-and-msgbox-not-working-in-excel-2010)

[FollowHyperlink event not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22113911/followhyperlink-event-not-working)

You could try an inserted hyperlink (probably not very useful) or piggyback on another event like SelectionChange, although that's likely to slow you down because the code will run basically every time you click.

Comment: by "inserted hyperlink" do you mean the Hyperlink.Add method?

Answer (score 0):

In a cell:

```
=HYPERLINK("#Tester()", "Click to Edit")
```

In a module:

```
Function Tester()
    Debug.Print Selection.Row '<< do something with the row
    Set Tester = Selection
End Function
```

Credit for this approach goes to lori_m: [Running VBA from a HYPERLINK()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32660492/running-vba-from-a-hyperlink/32662063#32662063)

Comment: That works, but it fires twice and gives the invalid reference error in the end

Comment: I don't see that.  Did you try it exactly as I posted?  Make sure that works before making any changes.