# How to clear a row cell values with macro in a data table

Tags: excel, vba

I use a table for work that has about 10 rows but I want to expand it to as high as 200. I use this table to keep track of specific tickets that I need to work on that shows me the status and follow up date. I use formulas in the adjacent cells to give me follow-up dates and specific comments based on the values of the first 3 cells in the row.

This is basically what I am trying to have setup... The first column of the table has a shape/button with a macro attached to it. I use this macro to clear the contents of the next 3 cells to the right of it. I want a button for each row of the data table to use as a simple way to delete entries. I use another macro to sort the table so that there are no blank entries between others in the table.

I use this code to clear the contents and have to edit it for a new row:

```
Range("B4,C4,D4").Select
Selection.ClearContents
```

Is there an easier method to accomplish this without having to write a macro for each of the buttons for the rows next to it?

Comment: I know how to copy the cell with the button in it down the table. If I can write code for one and copy it so that it applies to the right rows, that would be awesome.

Comment: You might find it easier to use hyperlinks for this - they don't have the same sorting/shifting/naming problems that buttons come with.  Eg: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38361689/excel-hyperlink-to-run-userform-based-on-row/38363257#38363257

Comment: I did figure it out. Thanks for the help though. I was trying to post the code but it looks all weird in this box.

Comment: You can edit your question if you have code to add (or post an answer)