# How can I use my VBA when Excel's hyperlink-following doesn't work, without getting two browser pages when it does?

Tags: excel, vba, hyperlink

> Unable to open yourURL. Cannot download the information you requested.

The above error message upon clicking a hyperlink in Excel is reported commonly online, for multiple versions of Excel (I have 2010, with Windows 7), with several stock answers that many users find don't work for them.  I am among the users who have tried several registry hacks and other solutions, finding none of them work.

I only get the error with some URLs, and not with others (so far, all of the ones that are broken appear to be https, but some https links work fine).  Of course, all of the URLs work fine if I simply paste them into my browser.  Firefox is my preferred browser, I only use Chrome if Firefox isn't rendering a particular web site correctly, and I don't use IE or Edge at all.

Upon coming across a couple of VBA examples for linking to web pages, I decided to try something myself.  Here is what I came up with (still needs to be pared down, I tend to be verbose during initial explorations):

```
Private Sub Worksheet_FollowHyperlink(ByVal Target As Hyperlink)
    Dim targetAddress As String
    Dim targetSubAddress As String
    Dim targetUrl As String

    targetAddress = Target.Address
    targetSubAddress = Target.SubAddress
    
    targetUrl = targetAddress
    'If Not targetSubAddress Is Nothing Then
    targetUrl = targetUrl & "#" & targetSubAddress
    'End If

    result = MsgBox("View Web URL " & targetUrl & "?", vbYesNo)

    If result = vbYes Then
    MsgBox ("C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe " & targetUrl)
    Shell ("C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe " & targetUrl)
    End If
End Sub
```

The good news is, it works for my most recent problem URL!  The annoying news (but less annoying than the links not working) is that the links that already worked are still working with the original mechanism, plus now my VBA is working, too, so for them, I get two Firefox tabs popping up instead of one.

Is there a way to suppress Excel's built-in hyperlink-following functionality for links to external web sites (it would be OK to use it for links to other spreadsheets, for example)?  Conversely, is there a way to limit my VBA to only apply to links to external web sites -- or better still, only to the ones that didn't succeed with the built-in mechanism?

Is this something I should submit to SuperUser instead?

Comment: Simple answer is you can't because the click on the link is executed **before** `Worksheet_FollowHyperlink` runs. The fish is already gone no way to catch it in `Worksheet_FollowHyperlink`. See link above your question.

Comment: If you structure your hyperlinks such that they lead nowhere, but still contain the info you need to construct the final URL, the initial click will go nowhere but your `Worksheet_FollowHyperlink` code can do its thing.  "Go nowhere" hyperlink - https://stackoverflow.com/a/38363257/478884

Comment: Thank you both.  I think maybe I'll just leave the msgbox in (originally included from some sample code I copied and edited, and I left it in for debugging purposes), and when the link works, I'll just answer "No".